# org-mode export to odt gone?

Tags: org-mode

Since upgrading to Emacs 24.5.1 and org-mode 8.3.3 (Kubuntu 16.04), I can no longer export org-mode files as ODT; only as iCal, HTML, LaTeX, or plain text. Is that normal? Is there a way to get ODT export back?

Comment: Maybe you could try `org-plus-contrib` ?

Comment: Great, that works! Pity that it's not installed by default in Kubuntu now, since ODT export was available in 14.04.

Comment: I can accept your answer if you make it an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: if odt export already existed in older versions of Org, then probably it was just disabled by default in 8.3.3 Org version. I do not know since I haven't used odt export and am using the latest version of Org. But I guess my initial comment was unnecessary. You just had to enable export to ODT in options. But hey, at least you got the latest version of Org now :) Shall I add this comment as an answer?

Comment: Yes -- I guess the answer, then, is to customize "Org Export Backends". Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable the ODT backend by adding this line to your `init.el` file:

```
(eval-after-load "org" '(require 'ox-odt nil t))
```

I know that this answer is rather late, but I hope this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on a comment by @Supernormal, I have `org-export-backends` customised as

```
(setq org-export-backends '(ascii html latex odt))
```

thus disabling a backend I will not use, `ical`, which unclutters the dispatcher screen - and adding the ones I need, namely `odt`